# Git and Github. Is it possible to make a commit on Github and not on Git?

Tags: git, github, repository, commit

I'm using Git on Linux and I have an account on GitHub. I forked a repository and added and pushed some files to master repository on GitHub. But then I edited a file on the forked repository on Github and added a commit via Github. I forgot to add a commit to Git by a terminal.

And now if I want to push a file to a GitHub an error shows up. I checked the git status and there is some commit to push.

I am new about this and I am not sure if its possible to edit a file on GitHub, make a commit and not do this on Git?
What should I do next to start pushing my changes?

Comment: No you cant' but you can clone the repo to a fresh location, make your changes and push them.

Comment: @n00dl3 `git pull` won't do the trick?

Comment: @scharette Maybe. I'm not sure I understand the question, it is so vague...

Comment: @Kejk what is the error ?

Comment: @n00dl3 from what I understand he made changes directly on Github, so his local repo is now out of sync. Therefore, I think he should pull changes from Github.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to understand the difference between Git and Github.

**Git**

Git is a revision control system which allows you to manage your code.

**Github**

Github is only a hosting service. Therefore, you use it to store your git repository. It comes with many features also.

Now to answer your question, if you made changes to your project on GitHub and not on your local machine it is no big deal. it only means you're out of sync with the version on Github. So what you probably want to do is run:

```
git pull
```

This way, you'll get the latest version from Github.

Note that my solution is assuming the changes you made on Github are changes you want to appear on your project locally.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I run git pull, and this is what I get: 
Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
 Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
 as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.

Comment: Edit. It tourned out that I had unmerged files, so I fixed them by adding changes. Now everything is ok, I can push files to repository. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: No problem ! The key thing to remember is that your local version and the one on Github are two completely different repo. They're just linked together since they're both git repositories.

Comment: @Kejk by the way, it is a good practice to accept helpful answers since it close the question.